# Kafka Offsets information not available

Tags: apache-kafka, offset

When I login to my Kafka Manager(version 0.8.2.0), I can see the latest offset information for each topic and partition. I want to be able to get latest offsets programmatically. So I followed the example on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Committing+and+fetching+consumer+offsets+in+Kafka but I do not get anything in response.

Also then I read on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+data+structures+in+Zookeeper
that offset information should be saved in Zookeeper under /consumers/[groupId]/offsets/[topic]/[partitionId] -> long (offset)

So I checked my Zookeeper (listed in Kafka Manager, under Cluster Information) and I do not see anything under /consumer (basically an empty document).

Can someone please help me to find this information? Is there something wrong with my Kafka configuration that latest offsets are not stored under /consumer? But then, where is the Kafka Manager getting that information from? Some other Zookeeper?

Answer (score 0):

The information related to the offsets it's handled by kafka now, so the information it's stored in a private (not deletable) topic call "__consumer_offsets-" you can find where this topic by checking the log.dirs property in "config/server.properties"

Comment: I do see a topic __consumer_offsets present in my list of topics but it does not have any data (all offsets for all partitions are 0). In the same cluster, there are other topics that contains data, so __consumer_offsets should have something present in it - How can I check for that? That Api is still not returning me any information. Also, who is supposed to update __consumer_offsets, could it be a configuration problem?

Comment: The offset of the consumers can be updated by kafka if enable.auto.commit =true.
The __consumer_offsets will have data if you have consumers consuming data, and you should be able to see that in the log of your consumer.